# Writing html tags in GWT client side

Tags: gwt

I have this code in my gwt client side:

```
        String out = result.getConsoleOutput().replaceAll("\n", "<br/>");
        transOut.getElement().setInnerText(out);
```

Basically what comes out of consoleoutput() is text from a telnet client and transOut is a HTMLPanel in a UiBinder.  I want it to show up pretty so I tried to change all the \n to html 
, but when it shows up in firefox it looks like this on screen blah blah
blah blah...
.  I am guessing gwt escapes the text somewhere how can I get it to write the real tag.

here is an image:

http://www.faciletek.com/errimage.png

Comment: do some screenshots, I am quite confused of what do you exactly mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to:

```
String out = result.getConsoleOutput().replaceAll("\n", "<br/>");
transOut.getElement().setInnerHTML(out);
```

Note the `setInnerHTML()` instead of `setInnerText()`

Comment: Although setInnerHTML works, I would recommend NOT using it. Its an open invitation to XSS attacks if you are not careful in escaping user input. GWT provides several ways to dynamically create user interfaces; always prefer them over setInnerHTML()